# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, typeerror

I'm working on a NodeJS Project that uses Sails.js as a framework.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a permissions system where the permissions per group are set by Check Boxes, I'm using a typical form with AngularJS.

When I click my "Sumbit" button it throws this error at my Browser's console:

```
angular.1.3.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at $parseFunctionCall (angular.1.3.js:12333)
at callback (angular.1.3.js:22949)
at Scope.$eval (angular.1.3.js:14383)
at Scope.$apply (angular.1.3.js:14482)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.1.3.js:22954)
at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (angular.1.3.js:3011)(anonymous function) @ angular.1.3.js:11594
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT Forgot the Code:
Here is the code that receives the information POSTed from the form

```
createGroup: function(req, res) {
Groups.create({
  groupName: req.param('groupName'),
  canViewUsers: req.param('canViewUsers'),
  canEditUsers: req.param('canEditUsers'),
  canPromoteToStaff: req.param('canPromoteToStaff'),
  canViewNotes: req.param('canViewNotes'),
  canEditPermissions: req.param('canEditPermissions')
});
```

Here is the code for that catches the information and POSTs it to the create function

```
angular.module('GroupsModule').controller('GroupsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr) {

$scope.createGroup = {
    loading: false
  };

$scope.createGroupForm = function(){

// Set the loading state (i.e. show loading spinner)
$scope.createGroup.loading = true;


// Submit request to Sails.
$http.post('/createGroup', {
  groupName: $scope.createGroupForm.groupName,
  canViewUsers: $scope.createGroupForm.canViewUsers,
  canEditUsers: $scope.createGroupForm.canEditUsers,
  canPromoteToStaff: $scope.createGroupForm.canPromoteToStaff,
  canViewNotes: $scope.createGroupForm.canViewNotes,
  canEditPermissions: $scope.createGroupForm.canEditPermissions
})
  .then(function onSuccess(sailsResponse){
    window.location = '/groups';
  })
  .catch(function onError(sailsResponse){

    // Handle known error type(s).
    // If using sails-disk adpater -- Handle Duplicate Key
    var groupAlreadyExists = sailsResponse.status == 409;

    if (groupAlreadyExists) {
      toastr.error('That group already exists', 'Error');
    }

  })
  .finally(function eitherWay(){
    $scope.createGroup.loading = false;
  })
```

There are closing brackets but they aren't getting formatted correctly in the post.

And finally here is the code for the Form itself:

```
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/angular-toastr.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.3.1.1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/theme.min.css">
<!--STYLES END-->
<body ng-app="DashboardModule" ng-controller="DashboardController" ng-cloak>
<div class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="bs-component">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Insomnia eSports</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/groups"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Group Management </a></li>
            </ul>

            <!--
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/logout">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form ng-submit="createGroupForm()" id="create-group-form" class="form-signin" name="createGroupForm">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create an account</h2>
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Group Name -->
      <label>Group Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Group Name" name="groupName" ng-model="createGroupForm.name" ng-maxlength="25" required>

    </div>

    <!-- Can View Users -->
      <label>View Users?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="canViewUsers" ng-model="canViewUsers.value">

    <!-- Can View Users -->
      <label>Edit Users?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="canEditUsers" ng-model="canEditUsers.value">

    <!-- Can Promote To Staff -->
      <label>Promote to Staff?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="canPromoteToStaff" ng-model="canPromoteToStaff.value">


    <!-- Can Promote To Staff -->
      <label>Can view notes?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="canViewNotes" ng-model="canViewNotes.value">

    <!-- Can Promote To Staff -->
      <label>Can edit permissions?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="canEditPermissions" ng-model="canEditPermissions.value">

  <br/>

  <!-- Disable signup button until the form has no errors -->
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="createGroupForm.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="!createGroupForm.loading">Create Group</span>
    <span class="overlord-loading-spinner fa fa-spinner" ng-show="createGroupForm.loading" ></span>
    <span ng-show="createGroupForm.loading">Preparing your new group...</span>
  </button>

  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
</form>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/Base64.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular-toastr.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/compareTo.module.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/signup/SignupModule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/groups/GroupsModule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardModule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/homepage/HomepageModule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardController.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/groups/GroupsController.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/homepage/HomepageController.js"></script>
<script src="/js/public/signup/SignupController.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
</body>
```

Comment: show us code...

Comment: Please add the relevant code (probably the template and controller/component).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access a single value as if it were an array, but again, can't say anything without a snippet of code.

Comment: @TomaszKaminski I have edited my code, sorry for the horrible formatting I'm not yet used to the formatting of StackOverflow

Comment: I've added the code from hastebin, using SO formatting is kinda easy... paste the code, select it, press "code" on editor and that's it. As for your problem, it is still not clear where and why it happens, I guess it is has to do with the response.

Comment: Thank you so much @ZivWeissman !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by me incorrectly using $scope on createGroupForm instead of just createGroup. The corrected code bit is below:

Instead of:

```
$scope.createGroupForm.canViewUsers
```

Use:

```
$scope.createGroup.canViewUsers
```